# LabVIEW - Store very large 3D array (array of images)

Tags: memory-management, large-data, labview

I am working on a LabVIEW project on which I have to process some video (with for example 5000 images of 640*480 pixels, so lot of data to process). Using a for loop I am processing one image at the time so in this side all is okay. But in the other side, I have to store the results to visualise the results of the wished image after the processing. Until now I always worked with array but here LabVIEW has not enough memory to do the job (which is quite normal).

Is there a best way to change my way to deal with the data, using other solution such as cluster, save the image on the local disk, etc?

For information, the processing is quite long (several minutes for only one image) and I don't have to save the result before the user ask for so I am anticipating the case where all the video is processed without saving the result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much RAM do you have? Assuming 4 bytes per pixel, 5000 640 x 480 images would take about 6 GB, so if you have 16 GB RAM or more then you might be able to handle this data in RAM as long as you're using 64-bit LabVIEW and you're careful about how memory is allocated - read through [VI Memory Usage](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvconcepts/vi_memory_usage/) from the help, for a start.

Alternatively you can look at storing the data on disk in a format where you can access an arbitrary chunk from the file. I haven't used it much myself but HDF5 seems to be the obvious choice - if you're on Windows you can install [the LiveHDF5 library](https://www.upvi.net/main/index.php/products/lvhdf5) from the VI package manager.

Comment: Bad luck, I have the 32bits version so I am limited to 4 Gb. Finally I decrease a lot the time of processing so now I am saving the results in a file because I had not the time to find another solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to store images as files in the system temporary directory and delete it afterwards? Since the processing takes long time per image, it should be easily possible to have a "image queue" of 5 images always loaded into memory (to avoid aby performance drop due to loading from file right before the processing) and rest would sit on the disk.

Comment: After the process, the user will visualize any image of the result so I have to keep somewhere the results. If I store it on the local disk, it will need at least the same size of the input video to store all results. But it is always a "easy" solution.